# Proving an inequality in number theory.

Tags: number-theory

I am going through Apostol's number theory text and there is a step in the proof of theorem 4.1 that is not clear to me.
It  is this inequality which I am not understanding how to prove.
$$\sum_{ 2 \leq  m\leq \log_{2}x} x^{1/m} \log \left(x^{1/m}\right) \leq \log_{2}x \sqrt{x} \log(\sqrt x)$$

Comment: I don't quite understand the summation index in your sum; $\log_2 x$ is in general not a natural number. Perhaps you want the floor of $\log_2 x$?

Comment: 6 months a member already, and several questions asked. Mathjax should be better used here. Is that $\;\log_2 x\cdot\sqrt x\;$ or else $\;\log_x\left(x\sqrt x\right)\;$ ?

Comment: @EdwardEvans I think that means if $\log_2 x$ is $4.3$ for example, $m$ runs from $2$ to $4$.

Comment: @vitamind is this standard in analytic number theory? :P

Comment: @EdwardEvans I've seen it multiple times.

Comment: @ edward evans, m is an integer...by log_{2}x, what I meant was the floor of it.

Comment: @EdwardEvans Yes, it usually is.

Comment: I was unaware :)

Comment: @donantonio, i have checked it multiple times before posting and it is the former expresesion, i.e., $log_{2}x.\sqrt(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest term is $\sqrt x\log( \sqrt x)$, and there are fewer than $\log_2 x$ of them.